# Cannot get return execution result form jupyter zmq channel when send meesage to it

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

When I trying to connect to its jupyter client in python code ,I encount a problem.

In the source code of jupyter,  connection to zmq channel was established when websocket is opened

```
def open(self, kernel_id):
    super(ZMQChannelsHandler, self).open()
    try:
        self.create_stream()
    except web.HTTPError as e:
        for channel, stream in self.channels.items():
            if not stream.closed():
                stream.close()
        self.close()
    else:
        for channel, stream in self.channels.items():
            //this is callback function when receive message from zqm channel
            stream.on_recv_stream(self._on_zmq_reply)
```

while in the create_stream function, the zmq channel was established.

```
def create_stream(self):
    km = self.kernel_manager
    identity = self.session.bsession
    for channel in ('shell', 'iopub', 'stdin'):
        meth = getattr(km, 'connect_' + channel)
        self.channels[channel] = stream = meth(self.kernel_id, identity=identity)
        stream.channel = channel
        ... ignore no significance code
```

when the server receive message, on_message was invoke

```
def on_message(self, msg):
    if not self.channels:
        return
    if isinstance(msg, bytes):
        msg = deserialize_binary_message(msg)
    else:
        msg = json.loads(msg)
    channel = msg.pop('channel', None)
    if channel is None:
        channel = 'shell'
    if channel not in self.channels:
        return
    stream = self.channels[channel]
    self.session.send(stream, msg)
```

At this time, zmq channel receive python code to be executed. After that, the execution result should be return, thus the function on_recv_stream above should be called and we got the result finally.

So I write the python code snippet like this:

```
from jupyter_client.multikernelmanager import MultiKernelManager
from jupyter_client.session import Session

from tornado import gen, web
from tornado.concurrent import Future
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

km = MultiKernelManager()

kernelid = km.start_kernel()

kernel =km.get_kernel(kernelid)

channel =  km.connect_shell(kernelid)

print 'channel', channel


def on_reply(msg):
    print 'we got return'

def on_timeout():
    print("Timeout waiting for kernel_info_reply: %s", kernel_id)

kernel.session.send(channel, 'kernel_info_request')
channel.on_recv(on_reply)
```

Actually, I did not get the return message, that is to say,the  on_reply function was not invoked. I did not what the problem is, Can anynone help me?

Comment: `connect_shell` is giving you a ZMQ *socket*, not a *stream*, which would have callbacks. To get a stream, call `kernel.client()` to get a KernelClient object, then `kc.start_channels()` to set up its channels. To use a stream, however, you need to be running pyzmq's event loop. Here are the docs for that: http://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eventloop.html?highlight=on_recv

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem like this:

```
from jupyter_client.multikernelmanager import MultiKernelManager


km = MultiKernelManager()

kernelid = km.start_kernel('python2')

kn =km.get_kernel(kernelid)

kc = kn.client()

kc.start_channels()

msg_id = kc.execute('import math\nprint(math.sqrt(2))')

while True:
try:
    msg = kc.get_iopub_msg()
    print('\niopub msg is')
    print(msg)
except Excption,e:
    print(e)
    break

if msg['parent_header'].get('msg_id') != msg_id:
    continue

msg_type = msg['msg_type']
content = msg['content']

print('content is :')
print(content)

if msg_type == 'status':
    if content['execution_state'] == 'idle':
        break
    else:
        continue
```